# Как безопасно передать пароль из Андроид приложения на PHP сервер

Tags: php, java, android, криптография, криптоаналитика

На сервере храняться пароли зашифрованные с помощью метода Blowfish. Например

```
$2a$10$dfda807d832b094184faeu1elwhtR2Xhtuvs3R9J1nfRGBCudCCzC
```

Со стороны Андроида посылается логин и пароль в незашифрованном виде на сервер, где с помощью соли из пароля на сервере и переданного пароля генерируется такой же пароль и происходит сравнение.

Вопрос: Как передать незашифрованный пароль из андроида на сервер безопасно, то есть в зашифрованном виде и на сервере сравнить с имеющимся паролем?

Comment: Как передать передать незашифрованный пароль из андроид в зашифрованном виде? =) Вам наверно какой-нибудь md5 хэш надо слать

Comment: SSL подключение используйте.

Answer (score 1):

@Visman правильно написал, только почему-то в комментариях, а не в ответах. Для безопасной передачи чего бы то ни было на сервер следует использовать шифрованное соединение. Простейший случай - https.

Авторизация по https, даже если остальная работа ведется по http - давно уже стандарт для веб-приложений.

Comment: Дело в том что это не веб приложение а нативное. Передача осуществляется посредством HTTP-Client в Android-е с помощью POST запроса. Дело в том что логин вводится не на сайте каком нибудь а на разработанном андроид приложении

Comment: И в чем проблема передать по https учетные данные, введенные не на сайте, а в приложении?

Comment: это идея. Значит просто написать перез названием домена https://  ?

Comment: Ну, если на сервере с сертификатом все в порядке - то да, можно так и сделать. Еще иногда certificate pinning делают. Но это, в общем-то, не обязательно.

Comment: не к сожалению просто исправление на https:// не работает

Comment: Ну так это уже у вас серверные проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Пароль - это строка. Преобразуй ее по какому-нибудь одному тебе известному алгоритму (да хоть слога местами поменяй, а все числа умнож на 17 или промежуточных букв напихай по какому-нибудь правилу - грубо говоря), а на сервере соверши обратное преобразование. В случае, если кто-то вскроет твое приложение и пороется в нем это, конечно, не спасет, но от простого перехвата пароля защитить вполне может (пока злоумышленник не знает формулы - для него это будет простой набор символов - не более)

Answer (score -3):

Blowfish сам по себе не безопасен. Попробуйте использовать AES-512 +  асинхрон. шифрование на Android. Создайте приложения для дроида....
Пример:

```
    Алиса кладет свое письмо в железный ящик и, заперев его на замок, отправляет Бобу.
    Боб при получении ящика, (внимание!) берет свой замок и, дополнительно заперев им ящик, отправляет обратно.
    Алисе ящик приходит уже с двумя замками (напомню с первым замком Алисы от которого у нее есть ключ, и со вторым — Боба, от которого ключ есть есть только у Боба).
    Алиса снимает свой замок, и отправляет ящик обратно Бобу
    Бобу приходит ящик с уже одним его замком от которого у него есть ключ
    Боб отпирает оставшийся его замок своим ключем, и читает сообщение.
```

Comment: В чем же небезопасность Blowfish заключается?